# AngularJS directive similar to rails helper

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I'm an ngNoob when it comes to `angular`, just started using it. I'm coming from rails and I really love a feature which is the rails helper. Basically I can do something like this:

```
<%= my_helper param1: "some value", param2: "some other value" do %>
  <div>
    This is some html that will get wrapped in html defined in the helper.
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The helper called `my_helper` would just capture the `&block` and put it inside some extra html and would resolve to something like this:

```
<div class="added-by-helper" data-params="some params from my helper">
  <span>Added by my_helper</span>
  <div>
    This is some html that will get wrapped in html defined in the helper.
  </div>
  <span>Other content from my_helper...</span>
</div>
```

I'm pretty sure this can be done in angular but I can't figure out how. I've read somewhere that `$transclude` might help but I can't figure out how to do that.

How could this be done in `angularjs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely correct that this is what transclude does.

Here's a simple directive that adds some content:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('exampleDirective', function() {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div class="added-by-helper"><p>Added by helper</p><div ng-transclude></div></div>',
        replace: true
    };
});
```

They key part is the `ng-transclude` directive on the inner div in the template it's the placeholder where the already defined content will be placed.

Here's the view:

```
<example-directive>
  <p>extra content</p>
</example-directive>
```

and it renders like this:

```
<div class="added-by-helper">
    <p>Added by helper</p>
    <div ng-transclude="">
        <p class="ng-scope">extra content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Feel free to play around on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/agAImd84TsqLvo1mCYzP?p=preview);

Comment: Wow. That was simple enough. Now I just need to find a way to pass a different `html` structure to the template that should get rendered outside the `ng-transclude` but inside the template. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the templateUri property of the directive

Comment: Thanks but that's not it. I'm already using a `templateUrl` because I don't like html in strings too much. I was actually looking for something like https://github.com/zachsnow/ng-multi-transclude